# Testopia: unable to add test cases to a test Run

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

Bugzilla 4.4. , Tesopia 2.5, Ubuntu 15 
, everything is updated and almost default by settings.

Every time I try to update/edit existing valid test case (priority for example) I have an error:

```
syntax error at /var/www/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 221, near "$field    qw(action effect)"
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 222.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 223.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 225.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 227.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 228.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 229.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 230.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 231.
Global symbol "$field" requires explicit package name at /var/www
/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 232.
syntax error at /var/www/html/tr_process_case.cgi line 233, near "}"
/var/www/html/tr_process_case.cgi has too many errors.
```

I have checked tr_process_case.cgi - everything is as default. Also I am not able to add any existing test cases for the test runs. Test cases and Test runs can be created no problem. But when I try to actually add cases to the run, testopia shows message, that everything is OK and all test cases successfully added to a run, but the run is absolutely empty. 

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: /var/www/html/tr_process_case.cgi 
    find line foreach my $field qw(action effect) {
replace it with foreach my $field (qw(action effect)) {
Solves #1 Error. But still can not add cases to run.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the fix and a patch to this issue here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=931961

Essentially, use Notepad++ (on Windows) or gedit and edit the file bugzilla\tr_process_case.cgi:

Then around line 221 change this line:

foreach my $field qw(action effect) {

to this:

foreach my $field (qw(action effect)) {

And that fixes it, confirmed.